# Upgraded to macOS Mojave and now getting error in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, fork, macos-mojave

Upgraded to Mojave two days ago. Rails server is running but when I try to run activerecord stuff, I get error. When I try to run "Account.last" or "Account.new" or anything, it kicks me out and giving me following error

```
objc[38551]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in 
progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[38551]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in 
progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely 
call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set 
a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Ruby 2.3.4

Rails 5.1.6

Uninstalled few gems and tried but same error. It's killing me for last two days. And I am not only one facing this issue after upgrading.

Comment: Which database? Could be a compatibility issue in the database libraries somewhere.

Comment: SQL Server 2017. Using tiny_tds gem. But other projects with same database are working fine. Even when I use rails 5.1.4 with another project, it works fine. But not with 5.1.6. I'll try uninstalling some gems again. Thanks

Comment: Any workaround with sql server tiny_tds gem?

Comment: Anyone got this working,  ```export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES``` Doesnot work on MacOS catalina.

I get this error when I do ModelName.last in my rails console.
And then I see this error 

```
 objc[40269]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[40269]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Answer (score 5):

put this `export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` in your `~/.bash_profile`

if you're using oh-my-zsh, edit `~/.zshrc` and put this 
`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` at the beginning of file

and then reload your zsh config `$ source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: The ~./zshrc file change worked for me. Could you please elaborate the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Postgres?

I started getting this error when running puma in cluster mode (specifying workers) after moving to a new computer (running macOS Catalina). The issue seemed to be a result of my `psql` version. `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES bundle exec rails s puma` did work but I was not satisfied since everything was working without that env variable.

I moved my psql version from 12 to 9.5 and rebuilt the pg gem and it fixed the issue without the env variable:

```
brew uninstall postgres
brew install postgresql@9.5
brew link postgresql@9.5 --force
gem uninstall pg
bundle install
```

Comment: No I was using SQL Server 2016. Later I had to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: Similar here. I use homebrew to install postgres, v12.1 triggered this error. But v11 is fine

Answer (score 0):

A coworker ran into the same issue today after upgrading to Mojave.

The problem got solved **switching from unicorn-rails to puma** server.
So to get on on your daily work you can change the server in development/test to puma.

This is not a permanent solution but helps to locate where the issue is located and unblocks the developers workflow.

Comment: I get this issue when I use rails console. Any ideas around this?

Comment: In a similar vein, I've been developing on WEBrick while searching for a better solution. `rails server webrick`. Hope you don't need concurrent workers on local :/

Comment: There's also this workaround if you haven't tried yet: https://blog.phusion.nl/2017/10/13/why-ruby-app-servers-break-on-macos-high-sierra-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/ (tldr: `export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`)